# If number ends with 1 do something

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to make something like this:

```
if(day==1 || day==11 || day==21 || day==31 || day==41 ......){
    result="dan";
}
else{
    result="dana";
}
```

How can i do that with every number that ends with one and of course without writing all numbers?

Comment: I removed mentions of jQuery which is a library for manipulating the DOM, not doing math.

Comment: You could also turn the number into a string and use the slice() method to check the last value.  Not sure which would be more performant, but it likely doesn't matter.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah right, not gonna fall with that, jQurery doesn't know math... Dude jQuery is math!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just check the remainder of division by 10:

```
if (day % 10 == 1) { 
  result = "dan";
} else {
  result = "dana";
}
```

`%` is the "Modulo" or "Modulus" Operator, unless you're using JavaScript, in which case it is a simple remainder operator ([not a true modulo](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3amodulo_operator)). It divides the two numbers, and returns the remainder.

Answer (score 17):

You can check the remainder of a division by 10 using the **Modulus operator**.

```
if (day % 10 == 1)
{ 
   result = "dan";
}
else
{
   result = "dana";
}
```

Or if you want to avoid a normal `if`:

```
result = "dan" + (day % 10 == 1 ? "" : "a");
```

% is the Javascript Modulus operator. It gives you the remainder of a division:

**Example:**

> ```
> 11 / 10 = 1 with remainder 1.
> 21 / 10 = 2 with remainder 1.
> 31 / 10 = 3 with remainder 1.
> ...
> ```

See this answer: [What does % do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript) for a detailed explication of what the operator does.

Answer (score 7):

Modulus operator.  You can research it but basically you want to detect if a number when divided by 10 has a remainder of 1:

```
if( day%10 == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be solved by single line

```
return (day % 10 == 1) ? 'dan' : 'dana';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a string and use `String.prototype.endsWith()`.

```
const number = 151

const isMatch = number.toString().endsWith('1')

let result = ''

if (isMatch) {
    result = 'dan'
} else {
    result = 'dana'
}
```

I'm using it in some code that sets the ordinal. For example, if you want to display `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, or `4th`:

```
        let ordinal = 'th';
        if (number.toString().endsWith('1')) {
            ordinal = 'st'
        }
        if (number.toString().endsWith('2')) {
            ordinal = 'nd'
        }
        if (number.toString().endsWith('3')) {
            ordinal = 'rd'
        }
```