# Check if integer ends with 0

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How may I create an if-statement in order to check if an integer ends with 0?

For example, I'd like to have an if-statement like this:

```
var test = 107; //107 is an example it'should some unknown number

if(test is xx1 - xx9){
  //do something
}
else if(test is xx0){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: yes, i should better ask it this way, i have updated my question

Comment: `if (n % 10) /* doesn't end in zero */`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433364/if-number-ends-with-1-do-something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      var test=107;
      var isEndsWithZero =test%10; 
      if(isEndsWithZero!==0)
      {
        //Ends With 1-9,Do something
        alert("Ends With 1 to 9");
      }
      else
      {
        //Ends With Zero ,Do something
        alert ("ends with zero");
      }
```

> Example:

```
test=107;
isEndsWithZero=107%10 //7
Else part will get executed
```

> JSFiddle Link :https://jsfiddle.net/nfzuaa44/

Answer (score 7):

```
if (test % 10) {
    // does not end with 0
} else {
    // ends with 0
}
```

Comment: Depends on the language that you are using, Python wouldn't have a problem with (test % 10), but Java would.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(/0$/.test(number)) {
  /* it ends in a 0 */
}
else {
  /* it doesn't */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

//Use Modulus

var test1=110

if(test1 % 10 == 0){
}// Number Ends with a zero