# Combinations numbers can be added to give certain sum

Tags: javascript, math, sum

Having an array of integers (eg. 3, 4, 5), how can you find all combinations they can be added up to a given sum? (eg. 17)

For the example there would be four ways the three numbers can add up to 17:

- 5 + 5 + 4 + 3
- 5 + 4 + 4 + 4
- 5 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
- 4 + 4 + 3 + 3 + 3

How would you calculate this programmatically? Eg. using javascript.

Comment: Something with `%` [modulo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)  perhaps?

Comment: In your example incomplete combinations are allowed. E.g.: `5 + 4 + 4 + 4` (3 is missing). Is it right?

Comment: @hindmost Yes, it's is right. Not all the numbers in the array need to be used. Only the first example uses every number :-)

Comment: Is there an array of three (or so) integers, and at most six (or so) summands?  Or are the numbers much bigger than that?

Comment: @Teepeemm The array with integers can be very big, but there will only be one sum. They will not get very big, but i believe that doesn't change the code?

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you! I'll look that up, and get back :-)

Comment: @RobertDodier Will you please add an answer so that I can accept it :-)

Comment: @DSDeniso OK, I have done so. Glad to help.

Comment: The number of integer partitions grows really fast.  If the numbers involved are small, this will make your coding easier because you won't need to use as many optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general topic is called "integer partitions". Searching for that might turn up an algorithm you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (i make no claim on its efficiency though):

1. You create a data structure that holds a sum of numbers. (The value of that sum and all the numbers that compose it).
2. You have an array A and a target sum TARGET.
3. You sort the array A.
4. You create a new array B, initialized from A with the data structure described above, where each element in B is the sum of the corresponding number in A.
5. While(B has values)

   1. You add each of the numbers in A to the data structures in B (B will now have `B.length*A.length` elements)
   2. Each sum in B that is TARGET is a solution
   3. Each sum in B that is at least TARGET is removed from B

Note: If any combination of elements in A equals 0, then the program will never end (as expected). This implies that A must have all elements larger than 0

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it looks quite complicated. I'll just use Robert's method :-)