# Using javascript to put images into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to put all of the images into an array and then use them in a 'slideshow'... Heres what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function onload() {
    var i = 0;
    var imageList= [<?php
        $dir='/assets/splashs/';
        $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach((array)$files as $file){
                if($file=='.'||$file=='..') continue;
            $fileList[]=$file;
        }
    ?>];

    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage="url(imagelist+i)";
        i++
    },3000);
}
```

*Note: imagelist was taken from another thread*

EDIT:

I get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < global.js:3`

The current code doesn't work, so I wondered if any of you have anything different or are able to fix it?

Comment: Are you calling `onload()` ?

Comment: PHP code inside `var = imageList = []` is not create output, you should use `echo json_encode($fileList)`

Comment: Does your `imageList` actually get populated?

Comment: @Girish it returns `[false]`

Comment: @user3352340, `$fileList` would be empty so return `false` and why you are using `setInterval`?

Comment: So, the problem you are having is populating the Javascript array dynamically using PHP? Or you are having problems with figuring out how to cycle that array in Javascript, or displaying the images?

Comment: @user3352340, you should use this way `var imageList = <?php echo json_encode($fileList); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage="url(imagelist+i)";
```

Should be changed to

```
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage="url("+imagelist[i]+")";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function onload() {
         var i = 0;
         var imageList = [ <?php echo implode(",", glob('./assets/splashs/*.*')); ?> ];

         setInterval(function () {
             document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url("+imagelist[i]+")";
             if (i === (imageList.length - 1)) {
                 i = 0;
             } else {
                 i++
             }
         }, 3000);
     }
```

I've added a reset when the last image in the array is displayed it returns to the first. + tidied up your loop for images.

Comment: Seems like an ideal time to use the mod `%` operator.

Comment: I just googled that and could you please show me how you'de implement that in my code. thanks @Xotic750 :) . gonna try learning how to do that later.

Comment: Sure, do you want to create a question and I will post an answer, or perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript

Comment: And here is an example that is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/22175919/592253

Comment: thanks :) quite interesting, Funny I've never really needed it ever so not come across it.