# jquery make rainbow pattern with list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my html

```
<div id="mainMenu">
    <span>Thing 1</span>
    <span>Thing 2</span>
    <span>Thing 3</span>
    <span>Thing 4</span>
    <span>Thing 5</span>
    <span>Thing 6</span>
    <span>Thing 7</span>
</div>
```

how can i get thing 6 and thing 7 to have colors? it stops at them because it does 1-5

```
colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green', 'blue']; //roygbiv

$('#mainMenu span').each(function(i){
    this.style.color = colors[i];
});
```

Comment: You only have 5 colors in your array. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: @MikeBrant in all fairness - He doesn't ask why this happens. He asks how this can be fixed.

Comment: @Nilzone It can be fixed by adding two more items to his array that represent the last two colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it wrap around:

```
this.style.color = colors[i % colors.length];
```

The expression `i % colors.length` yields the remainder after division of both operands and will always be in the range of `[0, colors.length)`. It's also referred to as the modulo operator.

An even neater version can be made:

```
$('#mainMenu span').css('color', function(index) {
    return colors[index % colors.length];
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/kipaf/1/)

See also:

- [`css(propertyName, function(index,value))`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)
- [What does % do in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

Comment: tthanks. you are so fast. Can you please tell me though what is % called? I need to look that up to see how it work

Comment: @user3400321 I've added a reference to help you further on how to use % :)