# How to check if variable equal values from this mathematical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this variable:

```
var number = 0;
```

And this number is increasing all the time. Everytime the number has increased with 200 i want to run a specific code. Atm my code is looking something similar to this:

```
if(number == 200 || number == 400 || number == 600 || number == 800 || number == 1000){
//run some code
};
```

Since the number should, in theory, be able to increase infinitely i wouldn't want to compare the value like this.

Question: how to(if possible) check if the variable is equal to all values in this specific mathematical order(every 200 number).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does % do in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [remainder modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) `%` , dividing number with *200* and getting zero as remainder will give you numbers multiple of *200*

```
if(number % 200 === 0)
```

if you want to limit from number 200 and 1000 then you can put other condition

```
if(number % 200 === 0 && number >= 200 && number <= 1000)
```

Comment: It's also need to check if the number in range `[200, 1000]`

Comment: @hindmost `if(number > 200 && number < 1000 && number % 200 === 0)`

Comment: @hindmost No, it doesn't.  The OP has coded it up to 1000 so far, but doesn't want to have to keep checking the values beyond that: _"the number should, in theory, be able to increase infinitely i wouldn't want to compare the value like this."_

Comment: Note that [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) talks about this being the "remainder operator" now, with a link to a proposal to add a true modulus operator

Comment: @Adil `200 and number`, shouldn't it be `&&`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Modulus operator, what this does is takes a number and returns the remainder

```
11 % 3 = 2 Remainer
```

So what you can do is

```
if(number % 200 === 0)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the modulus operator and check for a 0 result

```
if(number%200 == 0) {
    //run some code
    }
```