# jQuery if sentence on variable odd number

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax, counter

I have a function that I want to run every time my counter is 1, 3, 5 or 7. I am confused about what the right syntax is for jQuery in this situation.

My try so far:

```
if (i == (0, 2, 4, 6)) {
```

This is one of the many versions that I have tried, and failed with.

What is the right syntax, both for every odd number, as well as a specific collection of numbers, for example '3, 12, 512, 2231'?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a question about basic JavaScript comparisons. I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the modulus operator in which the value %2 will either give a 0 or a 1 depending on the value:

```
if (i % 2 == 1) { // code for odd event
```

or do it for evens:

```
 if (i % 2 == 0) { // code for even event
```

What this does is divide the value by the number given (in this case 2) and returns the remainder. So if i is 5, dividing it by two will leave a remainder of 1, so its n odd number. If i = 44, dividing by two will leave a remainder of 0, so its even.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i % 2 == 1) //odd number
```

It's a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). See this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) for more information on JavaScript arithmetic operators.

Explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900665/6294054).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(i % 2) {
  // If Odd then do this
}
```

Is this not what you're after?

`i % 2` will return `1` when an odd number and `0` when an even number.