# 12 hour Javascript Clock Showing 24 time, Wrong AM/PM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am using js to render a 12 hour digital clock that continuously updates. However, the code I found online left me with a 24 hour clock and the wrong am/pm output. Right now it shows *13:33 am*. I have tried out other snippets of code here and there, some jquery examples, but nothing worked and a lot of css already went into this one. How would I convert this to a properly functioning 12 hour clock? Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the hours of the current time on the visitor's
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    // Add a leading zero to the hours value
    $(".hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
  }, 1000);
});

setInterval(function() {
  // Create a newDate() object and extract the minutes of the current time on the visitor's
  var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  // Add a leading zero to the minutes value
  $(".min").html((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  var time = (time + 24 - 2) % 24;
  var mid = 'am';
  if (time == 0) { //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hours = 12;
  } else if (time > 12) {
    time = time % 12;
    mid = 'pm';
  }
  $(".ap").html(mid);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">
  <ul>
    <li class="hours"></li>
    <li class="point">:</li>
    <li class="min"></li>
    <li class="ap"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `(time+24-2)` what is the `-2` for?

Comment: I got this online as an example, I don't actually know. I'm very new to JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is with this line:

```
var hours = new Date().getHours();
```

It takes the *current hours* which will be from `0` to `23`. For example:

```js
var hours = new Date('2020-01-01 16:00:00').getHours();

console.log(hours);
```

You need to convert this to `1`-`12` range by using [the modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript):

```js
var hours = new Date('2020-01-01 16:00:00').getHours() % 12;

console.log(hours);
```

The only thing needed is to make sure that midnight is shown as `12`:

```js
var hours = new Date('2020-01-01 00:00:00').getHours() % 12;

if (hours === 0) {
  hours = 12;
}

console.log(hours);
```

Second problem is when determining AM or PM.

```
var time = (time + 24 - 2) % 24;
```

is wrong the `-2` offset makes any hour incorrect:

```js
var time = 16;

time = (time + 24 - 2) % 24;

console.log(time);
```

```js
var time = 1;

time = (time + 24 - 2) % 24;

console.log(time);
```

Next, adding 24 to the hours is useless. Finally, the modulo 24 operation is unneeded once the `+24` offset is removed. In effect the *entire line* throws off all calculations. You need to remove it.

There is other logic that tries to properly format the hours but it's misplaced, since *this* code never sets the hours - that's already set elesewhere. This code only sets the AM/PM.

Lastly, the third `setInterval` is missing an interval value. Technically, that will still work but it will run the function very often. Based on the other `setInterval` invocations, it seems the intent is to have a delay of `1000` (it's in milliseconds).

When all of this is done, here is what the code looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the hours of the current time on the visitor's
    var hours = new Date().getHours() % 12;
    
    //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    if (hours === 0) {
      hours = 12
    }
    
    // Add a leading zero to the hours value
    $(".hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
  }, 1000);
});

setInterval(function() {
  // Create a newDate() object and extract the minutes of the current time on the visitor's
  var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  // Add a leading zero to the minutes value
  $(".min").html((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  
  var mid = 'am';
  
  if (time > 12) {
    mid = 'pm';
  }
  $(".ap").html(mid);
}, 1000);
```

```css
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">
  <ul>
    <li class="hours"></li>
    <li class="point">:</li>
    <li class="min"></li>
    <li class="ap"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix, and walking me through it in detail.

Comment: The am/pm won't ever switch in this answer because the interval has no ms used for the second parameter.

Comment: @AaronPlocharczyk if not supplied, it will use the default delay. But well spotted, it probably should have a larger delay than 4ms.

Comment: Never thought about a default delay for setInterval, but you're right. In any event, an interval that short is madness haha

Comment: @AaronPlocharczyk true, I've amended the answer to point it out because you're right - no need to change am/pm 250 times *every second* :P

Comment: Date objects galore

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that'll be helpful. It takes military hours and minutes in the form of numbers and returns an array of 12-hour time components (the hour, the minutes, and the am/pm).

```js
function get12HourTimeComponents(hours, minutes) {
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  if (hours % 12 == 0) return [12, minutes, hours == 12 ? "pm" : "am"];
  return [hours % 12, minutes, hours < 12 ? "am" : "pm"];
}

console.log(get12HourTimeComponents(15, 23));
```

The first line adds a leading 0 to minutes if needed. The second line handles cases where the hour is 0 or 12 specifically (because they don't work well with the `%` operator in the third line). The third line returns an array for all other cases while converting hours to 12-hour format and checking if hours indicate `"am"` or `"pm"`. To implement this in your code, you'd do this:

```js
function get12HourTimeComponents(hours, minutes) {
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  if (hours % 12 == 0) return [12, minutes, hours == 12 ? "pm" : "am"];
  return [hours % 12, minutes, hours < 12 ? "am" : "pm"];
}

function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var twelveHourTimeComponents = get12HourTimeComponents(date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());

  $(".hours").html(twelveHourTimeComponents[0]);
  $(".min").html(twelveHourTimeComponents[1]);
  $(".ap").html(twelveHourTimeComponents[2]);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  showTime(); //show time immediately when page loads
  setInterval(showTime, 1000); //and every second after that
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">
  <ul>
    <li class="hours"></li>
    <li class="point">:</li>
    <li class="min"></li>
    <li class="ap"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm assuming you have your own CSS to style this, so I left that alone. You'll notice that I got rid of a bunch of intervals. You only need the one. You can update everything once per second with a single interval. If this is not enough explanation and you have questions, please let me know by leaving a comment.