# why is this work in javascript? - simple question

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  i++;
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    continue;
  }
  alert(i);
}
```

why is this code working? cause if "i" be '4'
then 4%2 = '2'! and this 2 is not same with 0
then why is it work???
as i know "===" mean exactly same.
then why is it work??????

any help will be so appreciated thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? It does what the code says it does. (And 4%2 is not 2.)

Comment: `%` is modulo. `4%2` is exactly zero.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does % do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

Comment: modulus operator (%) returns the remainder after (integer) division so 4 % 2 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % operator is not a division. It returns the remainder, for which 4 % 2 is 0.

You can see the documentation here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Answer (score 1):

the % is for modulus and not for division.

in mathematics it defines the rest of a division, if a number is even divided by two the rest will equals 0 the modulus is commom used to find if a number is even or odd.

so it will work because 10 % 2 really equals 0