# Numbers divisible by 3 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a more advanced scientific calculator. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this type of calculation. I have an array of numbers and I want to check which of the given numbers are divisible by 3.

I would like both the collection of numbers divisible by 3 *and* the count of those numbers.

For example, on input of:

```
const collection = [
    { text: "0", value: 0 },
    { text: "1", value: 1 },
    { text: "2", value: 2 },
    { text: "3", value: 3 },
    { text: "4", value: 4 },
    { text: "5", value: 5 },
    { text: "6", value: 6 },
    { text: "7", value: 7 },
    { text: "8", value: 8 },
    { text: "9", value: 9 },
    { text: "10", value: 10 },
    { text: "11", value: 11 },
    { text: "12", value: 12 },
];
```

I would like to get output like:

```
"There are 5 divisible numbers by 3: 0, 3, 6, 9, 12"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does % do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

> I have an array of numbers and I want to check which of the given numbers are divisible by 3.

You have an array of **objects** holding a Number on the `value` key.

---

We can get the desired output by

1. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only devisible by 3
   `filter(c => c.value % 3 === 0)`
2. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to only get number from `value` key
3. [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to separate results with an comma

```js
const collection = [{ text: "0", value: 0 }, { text: "1", value: 1 }, { text: "2", value: 2 }, { text: "3", value: 3 }, { text: "4", value: 4 }, { text: "5", value: 5 }, { text: "6", value: 6 }, { text: "7", value: 7 }, { text: "8", value: 8 }, { text: "9", value: 9 }, { text: "10", value: 10 }, { text: "11", value: 11 }, { text: "12", value: 12 }, ];

let res = collection.filter(c => c.value % 3 === 0).map(o => o.value);
console.log(`There are ${res.length} divisible numbers by 3: ${res.join(', ')}`);
```

#### Result

```
There are 5 divisible numbers by 3: 0, 3, 6, 9, 12
```

---

If we want to exclude `0`, we can change te `filter()` to:

```js
let res = collection.filter(c => c.value > 0 && c.value % 3 === 0).map(o => o.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) with for loops, denoted by `%`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to filter out objects containing number divisible by 3, using modulo (%) operator. I have used `map` as well, to create an array of values, instead of objects.

```js
const collection = [
    { text: "0", value: 0 },
    { text: "1", value: 1 },
    { text: "2", value: 2 },
    { text: "3", value: 3 },
    { text: "4", value: 4 },
    { text: "5", value: 5 },
    { text: "6", value: 6 },
    { text: "7", value: 7 },
    { text: "8", value: 8 },
    { text: "9", value: 9 },
    { text: "10", value: 10 },
    { text: "11", value: 11 },
    { text: "12", value: 12 },
];

let divby3 = collection.filter((x)=>x.value % 3 === 0).map((x)=>x.value)

console.log(`There are ${divby3.length} divisible numbers by 3: ${divby3}`)
```

Comment: @Navro please check this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the % operator.
So if number%3 ==0  means it divides

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator.

Using it you can extract all numbers divisible by 3:

```js
const divisible = collection.map(x => x.value).filter(x => !(x % 3))
```

And print them:

```js
console.log(`There are ${divisible.length} divisible numbers by 3: ${divisible.join(', ')}`)
// There are 5 divisible numbers by 3: 0, 3, 6, 9, 12
```