# Check if Number in minutes is a hour mark (60..120..180.. 240 mins etc)

Tags: javascript

### Question

Figure out if a minute number is the exact number leading into an hour / hours.

### Description

I have no code examples, as its something I'm trying to figure out.

I'm trying to build a script that basically returns true or false if the amount of seconds leads into `an hour` or `x hours` ; otherwise if not it returns false.

I'm unsure exactly how this should work, as it basically just all the time should check if the amount of minutes - would be the exact minutes to lead into an hour.. (This being 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours, 4 hours..... and so on)

I do not need to know how many hours it is or anything; i just need to know if its true or false if the amount of minutes would be exact to `Is the amount of minutes an exact hour` hour timers.

### Expected Workflow examples

**The minute number is just a const/let/var input being (example: 59, 60, 120, 300, 673)**

If Minute Number is `0-59` Return false

If Minute Number is `60` Return true (Because this would be 1 Hour)

If Minute Number is `60-119` Return false

If Minute Number is `120` Return true (Because this would be exact 2 Hours)

If Minute Number is `121-179` Return false

If Minute Number is `180` Return true  (Because this would be exact 3 Hours)

... and so on, basically endless - it just has to return true on any exact `is minute an hour` part, otherwise false.

### My thoughts i had to complete, but not sure

I would guess you would need to check if the minute number is divded by 60 or something like that; but im unsure.

Hope someone is able to help me out, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: *number __modulo__ 60*…

Comment: This may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript/8900675

Comment: if you can treat `0` too as hour, then `number % 60` should get what is needed. Or make 0 minute a special case, and then for any value other than 0 `number % 60` should also get what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the modulo (%) operator

```js
function IsOnHour(minutes) {
  return minutes % 60 == 0
}

console.log(IsOnHour(59))
console.log(IsOnHour(60))
console.log(IsOnHour(61))
console.log(IsOnHour(120))
```

Produces

```
false
true
false
true
```

Comment: Thank you so much. LIsted as accepted answer due to it basically just doing the job right out the bank!

Thank you so much.